# How do I record clicking of my buttons, and display its value in the input box of my calculator screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, event-listener

So I'm trying to make a calculator but I've been getting stumped a lot. I want to have the clicking of my buttons recorded and but into the top box of my calculator, and also using an event listener. I want to use function(event) to display the value of the button (number of operation) on the screen, and also event.target.dataset.num to return the value and it for it to be stored as a new variable added to screen value.

My code is very rough right now, just need some guidance.

```js
//3.
//Changing colors of opertion colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green"

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//I need  variables that will store targeted DOM elements, input/outputs
//And I need to add an event listener to retrieve data from all buttons when they are clicked. 
const buttonOne = document.getElementById('number1');
buttonOne.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(1);
});

const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('number2');
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(2);
});

const buttonThree = document.getElementById('number3');
buttonThree.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(3);
});

const buttonFour = document.getElementById('number4');
buttonFour.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(4);
});


const buttonFive = document.getElementById('number5');
buttonFive.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(5);
});


const buttonSix = document.getElementById('number6');
buttonSix.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(6);
});

const buttonSeven = document.getElementById('number7');
buttonSeven.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(7);
});

const buttonEight = document.getElementById('number8');
buttonEight.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(8);
});

const buttonNine = document.getElementById('number9');
buttonNine.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(9);
});

const buttonZero = document.getElementById('number0');
buttonZero.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(0);
});

const buttonDecimal = document.getElementById('decimal');
buttonDecimal.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('.');
});
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-grey{
 background: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8  btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8  btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pretty implemented design, I leave an upvote to your post.